# How to add conditional validation in symfony 2.1 forms

Tags: symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate a property dependent on another property symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260705/validate-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-symfony-2)

I have an entity as below:

```
class Items {

    /*
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Title cannot be blank")
    */
    private $title;

    /*
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = "0.1",
     *      minMessage = "Price should be a positive number",
     *      invalidMessage = "Price should be in number."
     *  )
     */
     private $price;

     private $currency;

}
```

I am using symfony 2.1 form with form class ItemType.

I want to add validation constraints to $currency only if $price is valid. How can I do this? I want to do this in both from controller and if possible within form class so that it would be helpful to others as well

Answer (score -4):

I didn't understood the question. My bad.

I think this is what you're looking for: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_2/en/02-form-validation

Comment: I am using symfony forms and calling $form->isValid() to check validation. I want to add validation to the currency form element which is a input field only if price is filled out.

Comment: i think this is what you're looking for: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_2/en/02-form-validation