# Dynamic form validation in Symfony 2

Tags: validation, symfony

I need to validate my form dynamically.  For example, when the user checks some checkbox I will display (or hide if unchecked) part of the form, but how can my validation work with the modified form?  Currently when I hide part of the form I get errors due to my Entity validation rules.

I've tried to search for the answer but I get no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How hard did you look? Here are the first four results when I googled "symfony conditional validation"

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html
- http://shout.setfive.com/2013/06/27/symfony2-forms-without-an-entity-and-with-a-conditional-validator/
- http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-conditionally-required-field
- [How to validate a property dependent on another property in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260705/validate-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-symfony-2)

Not to mention that it's covered in [validation overview](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups), arguably the *the* place where you should have started looking

Comment: hm..thanks. if but knpunisversity way, "impossible" for me, because i get null when call $event->getData(), here i describe my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122783/event-getdata-return-null