# How to compare dates in validation?

Tags: annotations, symfony, symfony-validator

I'm trying to compare dates in my validation. The documentation says it's possible but It's not documented.
I'm using annotations and I want one date to be later that the other.
How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate a property dependent on another property in Symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260705/how-to-validate-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-in-symfony-2)

Comment: I'm using the newer version of symfony. version 3

Comment: yes true, but that question was answered 4 years ago with a very ugly solution. I'm looking for the cleaner solution I'm sure symfony 3 can provide.

Comment: The /best/ solution is to use `Expression` validation, as stated in one of the answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've eventually solved it using expressions like so:

```
     /**
     * @var \Datetime
     * @Assert\Type(
     *      type = "\DateTime",
     *      message = "vacancy.date.valid",
     * )
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(
     *      value = "today",
     *      message = "vacancy.date.not_today"
     * )
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     * @Assert\Type(
     *      type = "\DateTime",
     *      message = "vacancy.date.valid",
     * )
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(
     *      value = "today",
     *      message = "vacancy.date.not_today"
     * )
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "this.getEnddate() >= this.getStartdate()",
     *     message="vacancy.date.not_more_than"
     * )
     */
    private $enddate;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
You can convert the date format to timestap and then compare them both

Comment: You're mistaken. I'm using the symfony framework, which is a php framework.

Comment: I could if I wanted to just compare dates. But I'm locked into The Symfony-validation framework. I need to find out how to compare dates using annotations.